# Is it possible to have a regex in the replacement string of a rewrite rule in nginx

Tags: nginx, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I need a quite special rewrite rule but I can’t find the way to do it.

I need to map a uri to a regex to a replacement string built with a regex.

For example I have a `/pdv/plan-AGE44-ABC.pdf` uri that could be mapped to the following ones :

- `/files/AGE44/plan-ABC.pdf`
- `/files/AGE44/plan-ABC(version-1).pdf`
- `/files/AGE44/plan-ABC(version-2).pdf`
- `/files/AGE44/plan-ABC(version-3).pdf`

So the `(version-1)` part in the replacement string is optional so I thought about using a regex here.

An example of my rule :

```
location /pdv/ {
    rewrite ^/pdv/plan-(.*)-(.*).pdf$ "/files/$1/plan-$2.pdf" last;
    return 404;
}
```

This supports the first case (`/files/AGE44/plan-ABC.pdf`) but I can't find the way to support the other ones.

Any idea how I could do this ?

Comment: Are you saying that one URL could point to any number of target file names? If it's a finite set, you could try each filename in succession using `try_files`, but it is neither efficient nor extensible.